# How to create multi-backup database/table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Just want to ask. Is it possible to create a simultaneous back up in Mysql?

For example if I have **database1** and **database2**. All I need to do is, Anything that happens in database1 should be happen to database2.

Meaning the database 2 is my backup. And can I do this in different host? Let's say my database1 is in 192.147.52.12, I want to create the backup in my localhost '127.0.0.1'. Is there SQL query for that? Or should I need to create a PHP script for that?

Comment: mySQL has replication: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Ok thanks, i will study it now. :)

Comment: Ok, but the instruction in the web are for experienced Mysql user. Can you provide me a simple instruction how to do this? I am using WAMP server.

Comment: You may consider to hire a DBA (outsource part-time will suffice) to configure and maintain replication for you or start becoming an experienced user yourself

Comment: Hmm :( so this method is for professional? Anyway thanks for the response. :)